# Derive the condition for a line to be tangent to a circle

Tags: geometry, circles, tangent-line

Given the
circle
$(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2 = r^2$
and the line,
$ux+vy+w = 0$,
show that the condition
for the line to be
tangent to the circle is
$(w+vb+ua)^2
=r^2(v^2+u^2)
$.

I have a solution
but,
as usual,
it is messy
and I am hoping for
a nicer one.

I'll post mine in a few days
if no one has a better one.

Note:
When I entered this question,
a number of similar questions
were suggested,
but none of them
ask precisely
this question.

Comment: You are more likely to get an answer if you show NOW what you have done.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is straightforward: the distance of the centre from the line should be $r$, so$$\frac{|ua+vb+w|}{\sqrt{u^2+v^2}}=r$$

Comment: Yup. Thought of this later, but you did it first.